# Правильный перевод строки в JSON

Tags: php, json

Здравствуйте, есть строка, приходящая с PHP в JS.

```
var locs=`[{"0":0,"info":"249","lat":"50.908","lng":"34.798"},{"1":1,"info":"400","lat":"50.908","lng":"34.798"}]`;
```

Нужен вид в js:

```
var locs = {
        "1": {"info": "11111. Some random info here", "lat": "-37.8139", "lng": "144.9634"},
        "2": {"info": "22222. Some random info here", "lat": "46.0553", "lng": "14.5144"},
        "3": {"info": "33333. Some random info here", "lat": "-33.7333", "lng": "151.0833"},
        "4": {"info": "44444. Some random info here", "lat": "7.9798", "lng": "-81.731"}
    };
```

Сейчас json_decode() дает следующий вид:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [0] => 0
            [info] => 249
            [lat] => 50.908
            [lng] => 34.798
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [1] => 1
            [info] => 400
            [lat] => 50.908
            [lng] => 34.798
        )

)
```

Как привести к надлежащему виду сам массив в PHP?
Для полноты картины прикрепляю скриншот:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Смотрите второй аргумент (параметр) функции`json_decode` выставите в `true` и получите массив, а не объект и 3 аргументом укажите глубину рекурсии (в вашем случае 2). И не нужно тулить картинки, давайте более менее рабочие примеры, за вас никто не будет переписывать.

Comment: спасибо. картинка просто дублирует код, дабы увидеть контекст вопроса

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В PHP нет такого понятия, которое в JS будет нормально будет интерпретироваться как "Object", stdClass это просто обертка для доступа к полям. И она не удобна для работы, противоестественная для PHP

Совет 1. Используйте `json_decode($string, true);`, если парсите JSON в PHP - второй параметр `true` указывает на необходимость представлять JavaScript Object в виде обычных ассоциативных массивов PHP, а не в виде stdClass. С ними на порядок удобнее работать, чем с stdClass, перебор полей, проверки наличия и так далее - все становится очень простым

Совет 2. Не усложняйте себе жизнь колдовством с stdClass в PHP. Используйте обычные ассоциативные массивы. Если ключи массива строковые, он будет преобразован в Object:

```
$locs = array(
    "1" => array(
        "info" => "11111. Some random info here",
        "lat" => "-37.8139",
        "lng" => "144.9634"
    ),
    "2" => array(
        "info" => "22222. Some random info here",
        "lat" => "46.0553",
        "lng" => "14.5144"
    ),
    "3" => array(
        "info" => "33333. Some random info here",
        "lat" => "-33.7333",
        "lng" => "151.0833"
    ),
    "4" => array(
        "info" => "44444. Some random info here",
        "lat" => "7.9798",
        "lng" => "-81.731"
    )
);

print json_encode($locs);

/*
 * JSON-строка:
{
"1":{"info":"11111. Some random info here","lat":"-37.8139","lng":"144.9634"},
"2":{"info":"22222. Some random info here","lat":"46.0553","lng":"14.5144"},
"3":{"info":"33333. Some random info here","lat":"-33.7333","lng":"151.0833"},
"4":{"info":"44444. Some random info here","lat":"7.9798","lng":"-81.731"}
}
*/
```

Удачи! PHP прекрасен своим единственным "массивом" на все случаи жизни, который может все и сразу, а не зоопарком сущностей вроде "кортежей", "хэшей", "словарей" и прочей ереси ))

Comment: Спасибо!) Помогло

Comment: Да, обратите внимание на строковые ключи "1", "2", "3" и "4". Если они будут начинаться с 0 и будут числами, то PHP сегенрирует массив JS вроде `[0:{}, 1: {}, 2:{}...]` -> `[{}, {}, {}, {}...]`, а это не то что вам нужно. Если генерируете такую штуку кодом, можно использовать трюк с `strval()` для ключей, массив будет пересобран

Comment: Да,генерирую кодом. Только strval не помогает. Что я делаю не так?

Comment: https://prnt.sc/j4nzj9

Comment: Уже понял) перевел в json на клиенте и все заработало